# SQL: Order by count return only the first row

Tags: sql

I have two tables `products` and `product_views`.

I want to write a query that returns the products with the largest number of views.

`products` table has `id` and `name` columns. `product_views` has columns `id`, `customer_id`, `product_id`. The counting is based on the `product_id` column.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_views ON products.id = product_views.product_id
ORDER BY COUNT(product_views.product_id) DESC;
```

The problem is it returns only the first product. I think the issue is that initially the product_views table is all empty (all values are null).

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using MySQL since any other database would force you (correctly) to use a `GROUP BY` to use a `COUNT` in the `ORDER BY`. Older(?) MySQL versions are a bit too relaxed in that regard and will rather give you a broken result than an error. Try your data/query at - for example - sqlfiddle.com and pick another database, it will point out your error and once you fixed it, the same query should work on MySQL too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your criteria, the following should work -

```
SELECT
 p.id,
 p.name,
 count(v.product_id) as views
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_views v
 ON p.id = v.product_id
 GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY views DESC;
```

The query ignores customer_id, and counts product_ids based on the id/name groupings.

Comment: This works fine, but I'm wondering what does the `GROUP BY 1,2` line do ?

Comment: GROUP BY 1,2 is equivalent to GROUP BY p.id, p.name. It's based on position, ie. p.id is position 1 and p.name is position 2.

Answer (score 0):

Calculates count in separate script:

```sql
SELECT products.id, products.name, pv.count FROM products
JOIN (SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM product_views GROUP BY product_id)
pv ON (products.id = product_id )
ORDER BY pv.count DESC;
```

Example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcd0b1/1/0)